# How to prevent python socket messages from overlaping in console?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a Python chat system which uses 1 thread for the user input and another thread for message receiving and printing. The issue is: if I receive a message at the same time that I'm taking user input, the text from the message ends up on the input line instead of its own separate line. How would I go about handling this?

A short version of my code:

```
def receive(cl,buffer):
    msg = str(cl.recv(1024).decode())
    print(msg)

_thread.start_new_thread(receive,(client,1024,))

while True:
    msg = input("message:")
    send(message)
```

For example: if I receive "hello world" from the server while I'm writing "hello server" in the console, it would look like this

"hello world**message:hello server"**

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use two different windows for input and output.  Consider existing chat apps where there is a window to type your message separate from the window that displays both your messages and the other users' messages.  Otherwise, you can be typing as another message comes in.

Alternatively, use a `threading.Lock()` to serialize output.  Only the thread holding the lock can output.  Unfortunately, if you have:

```
with lock:
    msg = input('message: ')
```

No other thread can print anything until you finish typing your message.  Yet another reason to use separate windows for input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to make a GUI for the system so I can display incoming messages in a widget and handle input from another widget.